# @ManyToOne(optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL) results in duplicate insertion

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I am using spring along with hibernate JPA. When I am trying to save entities extra insert statement is getting executed along with normal values. 
I am using the below entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "search_filters")
public class SearchFilter {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "search_filter_id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "search_criteria_id",nullable=false)
    private SearchCriteria searchCriteria;

    @Column(name = "field_name")
    private String fieldName;

    @Column(name = "field_value")
    private String fieldValue;

    @Column(name = "filter_condition")
    public FilterCondition filterCondition;

    @Column(name = "time_stamp")
    private Timestamp timestamp;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getFieldName() {
        return fieldName;
    }

    public void setFieldName(String fieldName) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }

    public String getFieldValue() {
        return fieldValue;
    }

    public void setFieldValue(String fieldValue) {
        this.fieldValue = fieldValue;
    }

    public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public FilterCondition getFilterCondition() {
        return filterCondition;
    }

    public void setFilterCondition(FilterCondition filterCondition) {
        this.filterCondition = filterCondition;
    }

    public SearchCriteria getSearchCriteria() {
        return searchCriteria;
    }

    public void setSearchCriteria(SearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
        this.searchCriteria = searchCriteria;
    }

}

SearchCriteria.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "search_criteria")
public class SearchCriteria {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "search_criteria_id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id", referencedColumnName = "entity_id")
    private EntityField entityField;

    @Column(name = "group_condition")
    private GroupCondition groupCondition;

    @Column(name = "operator")
    private String operator;

    @Column(name = "time_stamp")
    private Timestamp timestamp;


    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="searchCriteria", orphanRemoval=true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     private List<SearchFilter> searchFilters;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getOperator() {
        return operator;
    }

    public void setOperator(String operator) {
        this.operator = operator;
    }

    public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public List<SearchFilter> getSearchFilters() {
        return searchFilters;
    }

    public void setSearchFilters(List<SearchFilter> searchFilters) {
        this.searchFilters = searchFilters;
    }

    public GroupCondition getGroupCondition() {
        return groupCondition;
    }

    public void setGroupCondition(GroupCondition groupCondition) {
        this.groupCondition = groupCondition;
    }

    public EntityField getEntityField() {
        return entityField;
    }

    public void setEntityField(EntityField entityField) {
        this.entityField = entityField;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

My Service Class:

```
 public SearchCriteria saveSearchCriteria(SearchCriteriaBean searchBean) {
        SearchCriteria searchCriteria = searchCriteriaTransformer.transform(searchBean);
        System.out.println("searchCriteria:::::::::::::::: "+searchCriteria.getId());
        //searchCriteria = searchCriteriaRepo.findOne(searchCriteria.getId());
        return searchCriteriaRepo.save(searchCriteria);
    }
```

Results:
After execution I am getting the below results

```
>  **Hibernate: insert into search_criteria (entity_id, group_condition,
> operator, time_stamp, user_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)**

    Hibernate: select entityfiel_.entity_field_id, entityfiel_.class_field_name as class_fi2_4_, entityfiel_.class_name as class_na3_4_, entityfiel_.entity_id as entity_12_4_, entityfiel_.field_desc as field_de4_4_, entityfiel_.field_name as field_na5_4_, entityfiel_.list_order as list_ord6_4_, entityfiel_.listable as listable7_4_, entityfiel_.search_order as search_o8_4_, entityfiel_.searchable as searchab9_4_, entityfiel_.summary as summary10_4_, entityfiel_.summary_order as summary11_4_ from entity_fields_mst entityfiel_ where entityfiel_.entity_field_id=?
    Hibernate: insert into search_criteria (entity_id, group_condition, operator, time_stamp, user_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    Hibernate: insert into search_filters (field_name, field_value, filter_condition, search_criteria_id, time_stamp) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    Hibernate: insert into search_filters (field_name, field_value, filter_condition, search_criteria_id, time_stamp) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    Hibernate: insert into search_filters (field_name, field_value, filter_condition, search_criteria_id, time_stamp) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

I dont know why the extra insert statement is executed at the begining?? Please help

Comment: I tried to test it with Junit . I remove the cascade=CascadeType.All property from search filter entity and I hardcoded the searchCriteria.setId(15) property it is inserting without extra insert statement. I couldnt understand why cascade=CascadeType.All  gives extra insert command

Comment: searchCriteria.setId(15);
        searchFilter.setFieldName("AND");
        searchFilter.setFilterCondition(FilterCondition.BETWEEN);
        searchFilter.setSearchCriteria(searchCriteria);
        
        searchFilterCond.setFieldName("AND");
        searchFilterCond.setFilterCondition(FilterCondition.EQUAL);
        searchFilterCond.setSearchCriteria(searchCriteria);


        searchFilters.add(searchFilter);
        searchFilters.add(searchFilterCond);
        searchBean.setSearchFilters(searchFilters);
          eventService.saveSearchCriteria(searchBean);